# emacs - Is it possible to align defs with clojure-mode?

Tags: emacs, clojure, indentation

I'd like to be able to align the following:

```
(def first-thing "some text")
(def second-longer-thing (str first-thing ", yep"))
```

Like so:

```
(def first-thing         "some text")
(def second-longer-thing (str first-thing ", yep"))
```

Can clojure-mode do this? It seems to have pretty powerful indentation abilities.

Comment: Please, do not.

Comment: While this kind of vertical alignment is considered good style in maps and let bindings, using it across several `def`s doesn't look good. Take a look at https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide and https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode#vertical-alignment to get more input on how to format your code.

Comment: I agree that it's not as pretty as an aligned map, but unless I want to use plumbing.graph or integrant for something as trivial as my example, I need to use defs. To me, a long sequence of unaligned one-liner defs looks bad, and a long sequence of two-liner defs also looks bad. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The style guide has an example like mine with multiple related defs with no intervening newlines (the min-rows/max-rows one), but happily the var names are all the same length... usually that won't be the case.

Comment: You could try if you can make `M-x align-regexp` work on this. I did some quick  tests but didn't find a working solution. Maybe you are more adamant on making this work. :-)